# Android add fab button to layout dynamically by json result

Tags: android, json, floating-action-button

i my app in MainActivity View a execute a task that give me a json result.
I would like to know if is possibile to add dynamically a fab button into layout of other view in the number of json result.
Example if my json result have 3 items add 3 fab button to other view layout
This is my code about json call:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("businesses");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String phone = c.getString("phone");
                    Taxi_Number = "tel:"+phone;




                }
```

There is some example to do this or is not possible?
Thanks

Comment: You can create fab button in separate xml file then inside your for loop you can inflate it in some Linear/Relative Layout

Comment: Yes, is a good idea but i have done the fab button into other layout view and not layout of view that have the json task

Comment: Use interface for callback